# Underlined menu in CSS with dropdown

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

I have [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jt93hs7v/#&togetherjs=MHaAc93dOh) menu as a ground to my web page. But I wonder how I could get that menu with a dropdown.I want the other tabs under each menu category to drop down under the slided underline.

```
.container {
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

ul li {
display: inline;
text-align: center;
}

a {
display: inline-block;
width: 25%;
padding: .75rem 0;
margin: 0;
text-decoration: none;
color: #000;
}

.two:hover ~ hr {
margin-left: 25%;
}

.three:hover ~ hr {
margin-left: 50%;
}

.four:hover ~ hr {
margin-left: 75%;
}

hr {
height: .25rem;
width: 25%;
margin: 0;
background: #343434;
border: none;
transition: .3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put subitems in your menu. Basically an ul inside your li. This ul is non display by default and when we hover on the parent li it will display the ul with a selector like this : ul li:hover ul{}

```
ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
}
```

[See on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt93hs7v/3/)

Of course you gonna have to stylize that example but that not the point.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jt93hs7v/4/ but if I put the sub items to the third menu button it mess up the list completely, why?

Comment: It was a problem due to inline-block width and spaces. It's a long and painful issue so I just change the width of the li to 24% instead of 25. https://jsfiddle.net/jt93hs7v/11/